# Scan through row elements whose classname is identical

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a number of links in rows, in a web page, whose class-names are the same. Like this:

[image]

I am able to click the first link occurrence using XPATH,

```
"(//span[@class='odds black'])"
```

However, I want to scan through the particular row and click on each odds (if it is present).
Any help on how to achieve this ?

Note: I cannot find the element using other attributes, as it will change dynamically as per the data.

Image of  reference source code:

[image]

Comment: Can you add link to this page to see how source code looks like? Is class name always 'odds some_color'?

Comment: @pawelmhm Yes.. its always the same for the 'Integers' in teh same row. pls refer the web site (www.sbobet.com/euro) ... I have also edited my question to include the complete source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the XPATH in this format:

```
"(//span[@class='odds black'])"
```

could you use it in this format shown just above your red box:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]table/tbody[31]/tr[1]/td[5]/a/span[2]/span/span
```

(you can get this format easily by selecting an element in firebug, right clicking it's code and selecting copy XPATH).

I have found in many instances I can add a counter for a tr[1] or some other path attribute in order to move down rows quite accurately. I can't really see your site to compare the xpath below but I imagine it would be something like:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]table/tbody[31]/tr[1]/td[5]/a/span[2]/span/span
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]table/tbody[31]/tr[2]/td[5]/a/span[2]/span/span
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]table/tbody[31]/tr[3]/td[5]/a/span[2]/span/span
```

then you can add a counter like "i"

so you would iterate the counter in the loop and set it to something along the lines of:

```
"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]table/tbody[31]/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[5]/a/span[2]/span/span"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that class name will be always 'odds some color' you can use xpath's [contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256195%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function. Xpath like this:

```
"//span[contains(@class,'odds')]"
```

will return all spans that contain string 'odds' in classname.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors are class aware so it would make more sense to me to use;

span.odds

Xpath treats class as a simple string so forces you to use "contains" where as CSS allows you to treat classes separately